# signal SIGABRT when destroying array of bodies

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, physics, box2d-iphone

I have populated an array of b2bodys. Using the following method:

```
-(void)populateBodiesToDestroy:(b2Body*)body   {

NSValue *bodyValue = [NSValue valueWithPointer:body];
[bodiesArray addObject:bodyValue];

}
```

Each of the bodies are joint one to another to form a chain. Using the above method I have populated the array.
I update the following method within the Sprite class every 1/60 of a second in the HelloWorldLayer to destroy the bodies and remove their CCPhysicsSprites.

```
-(void)updateBodies    {
if (bodiesArray) {
        for (int i = 0; i < bodiesArray.count; i++) {
            b2Body *removeLinkBody = (b2Body*) [[bodiesArray objectAtIndex:i] pointerValue];
            bWorld->DestroyBody(removeLinkBody); //signal SIGABRT happens here
            removeLinkBody = NULL;
            [self removeChildByTag:10 + i];
         }
    }
}
```

I keep getting a signal SIGABRT on the line:

```
bWorld->DestroyBody(removeLinkBody); //signal SIGABRT happens here
```

The chain also freezes. I am not sure whether the all or some bodies have been destroyed and it's just the CCPhyscisSprites which is appearing. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you destroy a body, you must also remove it from the array otherwise the pointer previously pointing to the body will become garbage:

```
b2Body *removeLinkBody = (b2Body*) [[bodiesArray objectAtIndex:i] pointerValue];
bWorld->DestroyBody(removeLinkBody);
[bodiesArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
```

Comment: the signal SIGABRT is gone but the chain still freezes as some of the bodies fall.